# WordPress use too much server resource, what does this mean?

Tags: wordpress, web-services, bluehost

My WordPress host in Bluehost. It was working fine, however the last few months the website has become very slow . I have rang them several times, they tell me my website uses too much computer resource. I have not touched my theme for a while(I did update WordPress and Plugins). I also have not added content for a while .

How can I find what's wrong with WordPress or my theme,I did change to twenty fourteen theme, same problem.

One of Bluehost technicians said the index.php in the root folder uses too much computer resource. What does this mean? That's WordPress files, I have just updated the WordPress, I think it should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

That's really hard to tell why is your website using too much resouces, there's a lot of reasons for this problem.

I suggest you to use these 2 plugins to find where the problem is:

[P3 PLUGIN PERFORMANCE](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/)

[MEMORY VIEWER](https://wordpress.org/plugins/memory-viewer/)

Check the memory usage of each page, also check if any plugin is taking too much resources. (Compare to your server resources)

You can also use [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) to check the time of each query, sometimes the problem is in your database.

You can also try to use a CDN and a CACHE PLUGIN:

[CLOUDFLARE](https://www.cloudflare.com/) is a free CDN it will deliver your files instead of your server that really helps by lowering your server "work".

[W3TC](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) the best cache plugin.

If everything looks ok, i recommend you to change your hosting provider or upgrade your resources plan.

Answer (score 0):

You may try disabling plugins one by one and see if your site speeds up.

Comment: I disable all plugins, same problem. Bluehost technicians said could cause by database.